# cell not resizing itself when using as nib "loadNibNamed"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-view

I created a tableview cell using stactView with multiple labels so they can automatically adjust the dynamic content of the label. And it is perfectly working in the tableview.

But now I'm in need to use the same cell in a view with dynamic content.
I'm calling the cell is like

```
NSArray * arr =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StaticCalloutView" owner:nil options:nil];
StaticCalloutView * staticView = [arr firstObject];

staticView.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"permit-pin.png"];
staticView.lblTitle.text = (NSString *) [feature attributeForKey:ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION];
staticView.lblDesc.text = (NSString *) [feature attributeForKey:ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION];
```

But the problem here is it is not resizing itself in this case.
For the tableview i use the AutomaticDimension but what should i use in this case so that the view I'm calling will expand or compress accrding to the data pass to the labels.  ??

[image: constraints]
[image: View]

One thing I noticed during debugging when I remove the bottom constraint of the topmost stackView then the stackview resizes itself with the content but the view in which it is showing didnt.

Comment: make sure you have given proper constraints to all labels...and also check label's `numberOfLines` property...it should be zero...

Comment: Can you add details about your view hierarchy and constraints on the label and imageView

Comment: @Mahendra GP and Arun B -- I have updated my question

Comment: any specific reason to put that into stack view...?

Comment: Yes first the description label content is dynamic it could be of 2 or 3 lines and Second the image on the left should always be in center as according to the title and description label height. For these requirements i use stackView

Comment: "cell not resizing itself when using as nib “loadNibNamed”", otherwise it is working?

Comment: @Mr.Bista yes when I am using it in the tableview it works accordingly. And when i call it seperately then it just picking the static xib size

Comment: How are you using it separately? Show some code.

Comment: In tableview I call it like this :     CalloutCell *ret = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"StaticCalloutView"];
 
and in the view I'm calling it like this :- NSArray * arr =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StaticCalloutView" owner:nil options:nil];
StaticCalloutView * staticView = [arr firstObject];

Comment: you need to implement intrinsic content size and define a class for your custom view if you want  to autosize itself

Comment: Hello @ReinierMelian Can you explain it a littlebit. So that I can try it right away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override in your `StaticCalloutView` class the `intrinsicContentSize` variable this variable allow the view autoresize according the content or whatever criteria you use, there are some UIControls that have this method implemented by default `UILabel` and `UIButton` are two examples

This is an **example** of intrinsic contentSize implementation, note that this `CustomAutoresizableView` will grow according to the number of items in `arrayOfValues` multiplied by 40 in height

```
class CustomAutoresizableView: UIView {

    var arrayOfValues : [Int] = []{
        willSet
        {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
    {
        get
        {
            return CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: CGFloat(self.arrayOfValues.count * 40))
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview) says

> For all alignments except the fill alignment, the stack view uses each
>   arranged view’s intrinsic​Content​Size property when calculating its
>   size perpendicular to the stack’s axis

The reason why it is not expanding is because of ambiguity in the width for the label. UILabel needs to know width to properly layout in multiple lines. Check and try these options

1. Set `numberOfLines` property of UILabel to 0.
2. Set `lineBreak` property to WordWrap
3. Set the width constraint for the detail
   label or the view containing the labels.